# ionic-content: padding or no padding?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to recreate something similar to [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#forms-floating-labels).
I've noticed that the input fields can't be inside `<ion-content class="padding">` because then they get an ugly padding. The button on the other hand, needs this padding, because otherwise it sticks to the side without any padding.

The following code didn't work, since that places the button on top of the input fields:

```
<ion-view view-title="Settings">
    <div ng-controller="ClickedCtrl">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-mode="fname">
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-content class="padding">
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="clicked()">
                Save
            </button>
        </ion-content>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

UPDATE:

This layout is what I want (notice there's no padding on the input fields, but there is padding on the button):
[image]

This layout is what I get when I use `<ion-content class="padding">` (notice the padding on the input fields):
[image]

This layout is what I get when I use `<ion-content>` (notice there's no padding on the button):
[image]

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or something to more clearly understand you're code and what you are trying to do

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 8):

You should use it like this:

```
<ion-content padding="true">
```

You can see the example from the [official Ionic example](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/)

Comment: Then please be more clear on what are you actually trying to achieve, as @Rvervuurt noted.

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example here: http://play.ionic.io/app/1662da9d9b7d
To achieve your desired effect place all of your text form fields in an element with no horizontal padding, so that the forms reach the edge of the screen, then place the button in a nested div with padding, like so:

```html
<ion-content>
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label">Email Address</span>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </label>
  <div class="padding-horizontal">
    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="clicked()">
      Create Account
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

See output below.
[image: Example output]

I only applied horizontal padding because I felt that vertical padding, which is added by default by the `padding` class[0], resulted in too much white-space.

[0] http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#padding

Comment: i did not see any differents padding and padding-horizontal to it both appear the same

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to use a Full Width Block Button:

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive">
    Full Width Block Button
</button>
```

And also your content directive **must not** have the padding attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing padding from `ion-padding` and add `padding-top=""` inside a `div` class.

```html
<ion-view view-title="Settings">
    <div ng-controller="ClickedCtrl">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list" padding-top="">
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-mode="fname">
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-content class="padding">
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="clicked()">
                Save
            </button>
        </ion-content>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```